# how can i create unit tests a view that returns data in json in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I was wondering how I can create unit tests for a view like this. I have several of these in my project.

```
def json_list_user(request):
    data = list(Us.objects.values())
    
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.client.get()` and check what data the response holds, starting with `status_code`.

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_json_list_user_response_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy("namespace_of_your_view"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

You can also check if data sent is as expected:

```
    def setUp(self):
        # create an object or few objects here
        Us.objects.create()

    def test_json_list_user_correct_list(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse_lazy("namespace_of_your_view"))
        # check if response.json() have proper object/-s
```